# How to use fscanf function to import mixed data of strings and decimals?

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have a `.txt` file that looks like this

```
I am: 25.787
You may be: 55.88
He should not be: 5576.5454
She is not going to be: 12.556

I am: 56.545
You may be: 13.987
He should not be: 6.455
She is not going to be: 12.67

...
```

I want to read this file and construct a matrix which is in the following form:

```
25.787 55.88 5576.5454 12.556
56.545 13.987 6.455 12.67
...
```

I looked at `fscanf` documentation and tried very hard but I can not understand it. Could someone please explain how I should construct my matrix?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with fscanf in this case.  Take a look at textscan. You might be able to use its pattern-matching capabilities. If not, you can parse each full line as a string and use custom logic to look for the semicolons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In almost any case of data import [**`importdata`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) function is a mighty tool.

```
grouplength = 4;
DATA = importdata('myData.txt',':')
output = reshape(DATA.data,grouplength,[]).'
```

---

```
25.7870000000000    55.8800000000000    5576.54540000000    12.5560000000000
56.5450000000000    13.9870000000000    6.45500000000000    12.6700000000000
```

Comment: Nice, Good function to know. BTW, what is the function of `':'` here? Are you splitting the data using the `:` char?

Comment: @SanthanSalai yes it separates the columns and then automatically creates a cell array of strings and a numeric array with all the data.